# PhpStorm : Use files from one project in other projects without copying them?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have one project which contains some PHP services that I use as a template in all my other projects.

Is it possible to add these files to a new project without actually copying them to the new project's directory? Or, they could be copied but I want changes to one of the copies to affect the template.

**For example.** Template project contains

- folder `service` with files "1.php", "2.php", "3.php"
- and folder `util` with "u1.php" and "u2.php".

I want to use these files in one or more new projects but without copying them.

- They should merge with the files of the new project and be treated as if they are in the new project's directory.
- If the new project also has a folder "service" with files "4.php" and "5.php" the files 1 2 and 3 from the template should show  there too.
- And if I were to edit `service/1.php` in the new project, the original file in the template project would get changed as well.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: That seems to be a bad idea to me, copy pasting is way better, if you modify it and introduce a bug, the bug will spread in every project

Comment: Bad idea (just as **Lk77** said). But if you wish -- use symlinks.

Comment: The better way is to make an "abstract" file that you can enhance / extend or use as is in your project (code classes, e.g. PHP classes). You can make your own Composer package (since we are talking about `.php` files) and reuse them this way. If it's not code but HTML templates or alike -- better copy&paste.

Comment: @Lk77 Yes but also if I want to add a feature I have to make the changes in every project. That's a valid point though, I'll have to give this another thought.